# Include landscape figure pdf into document

Tags: pdfpages, landscape

I have a large figure over 2 pages which I would like to include into my latex file. This figure is an external PDF and in landscape format already. I want to be able to reference the figure in the text via `\ref`, so it needs a label. The code below works fine, but as soon as I use the `figure` environment, the rotation of the image is wrong (no landscape anymore). I tried an alternative solution via. `includegraphics`, but the image was always too small (and somehow not centered). Is there any way to do that properly?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

Figure \ref{fig:document} shows\ldots

\begin{figure}[h!]
\includepdf[pages=1,landscape=true]{Figure1.pdf}  % exemplary landscape figure, 2 pages long
\label{fig:document}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

It doesnt really have to be a figure environment, as I do not use a list of figures. I just need to be able to link to it and reference it. Any hints highly appreciated.

Edit: Please note, in this case, a caption is not necessary. I am basically looking for a method to include a picture that already has a caption. But I want to link it from the text.

Comment: The `figure` environment can't span several pages. Therefore you should use the `capt-of` package (or `caption` if you already use it for something else) and the `\captionof{figure}{<caption>}` command.

Comment: @Skillmon ah I see, thanks. So just use `\captionof{figure}{<caption>}`, that's it? Maybe you could make a full example? I don't fully understand how to use the command. It throws errors atm when I am trying.

Comment: Did you use `\usepackage{capt-of}` or `\usepackage{caption}` in the preamble?

Comment: I am using `\usepackage{caption}`

Comment: `\includepdf` is not meant to produce something with a caption..

Answer (score 2):

You could include them in a `landscape` environment and then use `minipage`s to enforce that the caption is on the same page as the image. This will not lead to full width inclusion though:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}

Figure \ref{fig:duck1} shows\ldots

\begin{landscape}
  \noindent
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics
      [page=1,width=\linewidth,height=.95\textheight,keepaspectratio]
      {example-image-duck}
    \captionof{figure}{a duck\label{fig:duck1}}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \includegraphics
      [page=2,width=\linewidth,height=.95\textheight,keepaspectratio]
      {example-image-duck}
    \captionof{figure}{another duck\label{fig:duck2}}
  \end{minipage}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**A late edit:**

The following produces two clickable links that make the PDF viewer jump to the pages the two ducks are placed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\hyperlink{hyp:duck1}{the first duck} and 
\hyperlink{hyp:duck2}{the second duck}

\clearpage % important or else the first link is on the wrong page
\hypertarget{hyp:duck1}
  {\includepdf[pages=1,landscape=true]{example-image-duck}}
\hypertarget{hyp:duck2}
  {\includepdf[pages=2,landscape=true]{example-image-duck}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks, I actually had something similar working. The problem is that the image is pretty large and this method makes it shrink too much in the width.
P.S: nice duck.

Comment: I do not need a caption necessarily, I just want to have the image as large as possible, if that changes anything.

Comment: @ghx but how do you want to reference it if there is no caption?!

Comment: I don't know, I thought maybe by marking the area in the document before the inclusion of the file somehow and then link to the marker? That would be a workaround. I don't know if it is possible in Latex though

Comment: If it should be just a hyper link that opens that page on clicking, it is possible. But how should that help in a document? You can't have any number of something like that in the text. Maybe placing a hyper target and saving the page number could help. Is that something you want?

Comment: yes I think that's it. Well the figure as a PDF is already labelled and also has a caption. I just want to include it and refer via a custom link.